# With the meaning of "not involving anything else", could "just" and "solely" be used interchangeably?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

"Just" might be the most ambiguous word in English and confuses me a lot. I am trying to discuss each piece of its different meanings in a sequence of posts. Please focus this post on the meaning of "only and not involving anyone or anything else".

per Cambridge dictionary (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/solely), "solely" has only one meaning, that is, "only and not involving anyone or anything else".

With this piece of meaning ("solely"), consider the following example

> I don't like my job. I **simply** do it for the money.

[coming from one of the different meanings of simply on Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/simply)

obviously, simply shows the meaning of "only and not involving anyone or anything else", consequently, just, only, solely, simply could be used interchangeably, right?

The following example comes from the definition of "solely" on Cambridge dictionary

> The product's success cannot be attributable **solely** to the ads.

If I substitute "just" for "solely"

> The product's success cannot be attributable **just** to the ads.

Is it also idiomatic? Does it have the same meaning?

Comment: The interchangeability is limited. Especially between _just_ and _solely_, because _solely_ transports _exclusively_ in itself. That can be desired but doesn't have to _I just don't know._ cannot be interchanged to _I solely don't know._ Here _simply_ is the most suitable replacement for _just_.

Comment: In other words: You can use any of the stated words but you change slightly or even significantly the meaning of the sentence. As I've already alluded in my first comment, I tend to deny that _just_ and _solely_ are synonyms.

Comment: None of your references show the interchangeability between _just_ and _solely_. So, why do you ask for it? Do you have other references, which support it?

Comment: @BenA. I guess "just" in *I just don't know.* shows [the meaning of “Really(used for emphasis)”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238355/95044)

Comment: I had a wider look at the sentence which included _Stop weeping! But he's left me!. Why? I just don't now._ I would insist that in such a case _simply_ is the better translation as there is no reason for a _really_. No reason for insistence, for defense. But yes, there are also situations where _really_ is more appropriate as translation. By the way, would you please eventually decide if this question is about _solely_ **or** _simply_ as meaning for _just_. The question text is ambiguous again after you have reverted my edit.

Comment: Your question seems to be only the last four lines of text. If so, maybe you could edit it down to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Just" and "solely" are not always interchangeable, although they can mean the same thing, depending on the context.

For example, you could say "*he's just a baby*", meaning he's not yet anything more than a baby with respect to *age*, *growth*, *intellectual capacity etc*. You would not say "he's *solely* a baby" because that isn't any baby's *sole* characteristic. They are also a boy, a girl, strong, tall, etc.

A dictionary will tell you that "just" has multiple definitions, including:

- exactly
- recently
- barely
- simply
- no more than

---

All of your examples are perfectly idiomatic. Just (!) remember that the context can change the meaning, or at least the implication.

For example:

> It's just a job.

This could idiomatically mean that you consider your job to be *no more than* a means of living (ie it isn't your vocation, your life's work). It could also be a response to a suggestion that your job is special, perhaps deserving of high praise or commendation, to denote in a humble way that it is *simply* your job.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Thank you. There are at least 2 meanings that "It's just a job" possibly implies, right? Could you please add a bit context conversation for each of those?