# Is it clear and idiomatic to refer to one of different meanings of a word as "one piece of meaning"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, terminology

Oxford Dictionary (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/just) gives a bunch of definitions about “just”

there are 3 sub-items in 4th item, one of them is pointed out by blue rectangle in the following image.

[image]

I referred to each of sub-items as *each piece of its different meanings* in another post ([The usage of "just": with meaning of "only and not involving anyone or anything else"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238336/95044)), is it clear and idiomatic?

Comment: Your recursive question-asking won't lead you anywhere as there're obviously far too many holes to patch (and I'm not saying you're alone in that). Also, it's kinda annoying.