# Is it suitable to call a baby a "thing"? If yes, how old is a baby when he/she should not be called "thing"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

An answer to the question ([With the meaning of "not involving anything else", could "just" and "solely" be used interchangeably?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238336/95044)) says

> For example, you could say "he's just a baby", meaning he's not yet **anything** more than a baby with respect to age, growth, intellectual capacity etc.

Is it suitable to call a baby a "thing"? If yes, how old is a baby when he/she should not be called "thing"?

Comment: People disagree about the point where a collection of cells starts being a person. But I'm pretty sure all agree that that point is _before_ birth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a baby can be a thing, like a man or woman or student or professor can be a thing.

It's the difference between **who** we are, which refers to us as persons, that is our relationships with other persons, and **what** we are, which refers to "things," like our sex, growth status (baby, child, adult, old man), profession, membership of a community, etc.

Is it suitable to call a baby a "thing"? If yes, how old is a baby when he/she should not be called "thing"?

It's not that a baby is a thing and becomes a person at a certain age. A baby is always a person, but his/her growth status as a baby is a thing.

Comment: People often affectionately say of a baby, kitten, puppy, etc, that it is 'a cute little thing'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, yes, I agree. The OP thought that using "anything" in a sentence directly refers to a baby as a thing. A baby is both a person (who) and a thing in a certain development phase, so a thing (what).

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Thank you. Is it appropriate to consider the growth status as some kind of attribute/characteristic?

Comment: @WXJ96163,  yes, I'm an adult and this is my attribute or characteristic.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your quote is from one of my answers!

Yes, there are contexts where you can call a baby, or a person a "thing". In British English "poor thing" is a common expression when feeling sorry for someone.

However, **in the context of my answer, I wasn't referring to the baby as a "thing"**. I was referring to a *quality* or *characteristic* of the person.

A person is many things - a man, a woman, tall, short, kind etc. All these qualities could be called "things". For example, it is quite idiomatic to say "*tell me something about yourself*", to mean a fact, or a quality, or an aspect of your personality.

I said that the baby (who is a person) is "not yet anything more than a baby with respect to age, growth, intellectual capacity etc". I was referring to the fact they are a baby as a quality of the person rather than it meaning the entire person themselves. One day that person will be an adult, not a baby, so they will lose that characteristic, but they will still be a person.

Comment: Yes, my quote is from one of your answers and I claimed that at the beginning of my OP. Thank you again! I guess I've got a clearer understanding now. I guess it is reasonable to rewrite "he's just a baby" as "his growth status is baby". However, the rewritten version is a bit wordy, and any native English speaker would get the meaning with original one, so, it is unnecessary to bother say something like my version, right?